# If $T$ is injective, there exists left inverse $S:W\rightarrow V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I apologize for this repeat question but I've been trying to figure this problem out for at least 3 hours and haven't made any progress. I've seen other Math SE posts to no avail.

> Assume $W$ is finite dimensional and $T:V\rightarrow W$ is linear.
> Show that if $T$ is injective, then there exists a linear map
> $S:W\rightarrow V$ so that $ST=I_V$.

Like I've said, I've seen *many* Math SE posts and they all seem to do the same thing: The image of $T$ is a subspace of $W$;  hence,  finite dimensional. Then,  it has some basis $w_1,...,w_n$.  Moreover, since every linearly independent collection of vectors in $W$ can be extended to a basis of $W$, the basis of the image can be extended to a basis $w_1,...,w_m$ of $W$ (with $m≥n$).

Okay, so far, so good. I'm not totally sure why we're doing this but I follow what is being done.

Now, let $S:W→V$ be the linear map that sends each $w_i$ to its unique preimage if $ i≤n$ or to 0 if $i > n$.

This is where I get **so** confused. Why define $S$ for just the basis vectors? Moreover, why are we allowed to just set $S(w)=0$ if $i > n$? More importantly, how do we even know this is a linear mapping?

**EDIT**: Defining $S$ on just the basis vectors for $i \leq n$ case doesn't make much sense to me, but I can get around it by just defining it like so: $S(T(v)) = v$. But what I *really* don't understand is the $S(w)=0$ case.

Comment: This is precisely the power of a basis in linear algebra: any linear map is uniquely determined by the images of the basis elements.

Comment: @beginner While of course all the approaches -- that attempt to produce a retraction of the injective morphism $f$ by describing it on a basis of the target space -- are valid, this basis manipulation is in a sense a useless complication and also obfuscates the essence of the phenomenon. The property which is crucial for this kind of phenomena to work is the semisimplicity of vector spaces as modules, rather than the aspect of free-ness. In plainer terms, what matters here is that any subspace of a vector space has a supplementary and for this very reason *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @beginner (*cont.*) the claim analogous to yours above will be valid in the more general setting of an injective module morphism whose target is semisimple. If $f \colon M \to N$ is injective, $A$-linear -- $A$ being the ring of operators for the left modules $M$ and $N$ -- and $N$ semisimple, than the restriction $f'$ of $f$ to its image is an isomorphism of inverse $g \colon \mathrm{Im}f \to M$ and there exists a supplementary $P$ of $\mathrm{Im}f$ in $N$. The unique morphism $h \colon N \to M$ which extends $g$ and is null on $P$ will be a retraction of $f$. No bases required at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical linear algebra.

Given two vector spaces (finite dimensional or not doesn't matter) $V$ and $W$ and a basis $B$ of $V$ then every function $f:B\to W$ can be uniquely extended to a linear map $F:V\to W$. This is because given any vector $v\in V$ it can be uniquely expressed as $v=\sum_{b\in B} \lambda_b\cdot b$ for some scalars $\lambda_b$ taken from the underlying field $k$. All those scalars except finitely many are zero. With that we have $F(v):=\sum_{b\in B}\lambda_b\cdot f(b)$.

And so in order to define any linear map $V\to W$ it is enough to define its values on a basis $B$.

Note that there is no restriction on $f:B\to W$. We can setup those initial values to be anything we want, in particular there is nothing prohibiting us to define $f(w)=0$ for some elements from $B$.

> but I can get around it by just defining it like so: $S(T(v)) = v$

That's not a definition. That's an equation. And yes, ultimately we want that property to be true. But we want to define $S(x)$ for $x\in W$. There are two cases: $x$ does and does not belong to the image of $T$. If it does then we can simply define $S(x):=T^{-1}(x)$. Note that $T^{-1}(x)$ is a singleton, because $T$ is injective and so this is a well defined function.

But what happens if $x$ does not belong to the image of $T$? Meaning $T^{-1}(x)=\emptyset$. That's why this naive approach fails. We fix that by considering basis of the image of $T$ and its extension to full $W$. Defininig $S(w)=0$ on those basis elements outside of the image of $T$ is arbitrary. Any $S(w)$ will work fine.

The whole idea here is similar to classical sets: given an injective function $f:X\to Y$ how do we define its partial inverse $g:Y\to X$? Well, we define $g$ to be the inverse of $f$ on the image of $f$. For elements outside of the image of $f$ we define $g$ arbitrarily.

A vector basis allows us to treat linear maps as classical functions to some degree.

Comment: The entity which will certainly be a singleton is $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ -- when $x$ belongs to the image of the injection $f$ -- and not $f^{-1}(x)$. Depending on the precise definition of the latter notation, it can be construed as the unique preimage $t$ of $x$ which -- $t$ itself -- taken as a set has who knows what cardinality, not to mention that it is irrelevant whether $t$ itself were a singleton or not. What matters in this context is that $\{t\}$ is a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have (finite dimensional) vector spaces $W$ and $V$ (over some field $K$) and some linear function $f \colon W \to V$.
If $(w_1, ..., w_n)$ is a basis of $W$, then $f$ is entirely determined by the values $f(w_1), ..., f(w_n)$ because any vector $w \in W$ can be written as $w = a_1 w_1 + ... + a_n w_n$ (with $a_i \in K$ appropriately chosen), and hence we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(w) 
&= f(a_1 w_1 + ... + a_n w_n) \\
&= f(a_1 w_1) + ... + f(a_n w_n) \\
&= a_1 f(w_1) + ... a_n f(w_n).
\end{align}
$$
It follows that we can define any such linear map by taking a basis of $W$ and defining the images of the basis vectors (basically this is why we can use matrices to represent linear functions!).